# max length of httpResponse in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm using `UrlFetchApp.fetch` to retrieve the content of a web page. I wonder if there is a limit about the length of the returned object text content (by `.getContent()` or `.getContentText()` methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Fetch quotas are set by data sizes (100MB max per day) rather than character limits. Quotas are given on the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard).

This [SO post from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646003/google-apps-script-urlfetchapp-fetch-limitations) reports 30K+ characters in a single call. There is no documentation, from what I can tell, about max string sizes. If you're trying to log the string, that's probably why you're seeing a number, *n*, lower than expected.